# How can i replace { inside string in java

Tags: java, replace

Can anybody help me in replacing '{' inside string in java

For e.g.

```
String str = "abc{ad}";
str = str.replace("{","(");
```

But this seems to be not possible.

Comment: try str = str.replace("\{","\(");

Comment: `replace` replaces characters not Strings.

Comment: What JDK version do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{` and `(` are meteacharacters in java, you should escape them with backslash . and `String.replace` doesn't use regex, use `[String.replaceAll][1]` or [`String.replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\{","\\(");
```

Answer (score 5):

[`String#replace(char,char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) does it and fits for one character. All you have to do is switch your `replace()` invokation to:

```
str = str.replace('{','(');
 //               ^ ^ ^ ^
 //             not the ' instead of "
```

However, `String` in java is *immutable* so you cannot change it<sup>1</sup>, you can only generate a new string object with these properties.

---

<sub>(1) not easily anyway, can be done with [reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), but **it is unadvised**.</sub>

Comment: I would remove the note about reflection. It just adds noise, IMO, and could make the reader think that it would be a wise thing to modify a string using reflection.

Comment: @JBNizet: I see your point, but claiming "it cannot be done" is wrong without this clarification, I subbed it to generate less noise, I would also appritiate any edit that one may think explains it is should be avoided better.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for

```
String strAll = "abc{ad}";
strAll = strAll.replaceAll("\\{","(");
```